# Assert Statement for ternary operator in Rhino mocks?

Tags: c#, code-coverage, rhino-mocks

```
x(string)= y(string) != ? y : string.empty
```

How to get 100% code coverage for above line using Assert statement

We've tried using:
Assert.AreEqual(Actualvalue,ExpectedValue);
but we are missing code coverage somewhere

Comment: Could you please add the **real** code? The code that you have provided will not even compile! Also, 100 % code coverage should not be a goal just for its own sake. What are the use cases and/or requirements that you need to test for?

Comment: sorry we cannot provide the real code for the sake of compliance issue but we just want to know how can we cover a ternary operator using assert statement under code coverage. Moreover as per our use case we have to cover it under code coverage.

Comment: Basically you need two test-cases for 100% coverage, one for the condition `y != ...` passing and one for it failing. However depending on what this condition is you may have to add more cases. So either implement two test-methods or create one and apply the `TestCase`-attribute with a `Result`-param to it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere we have already tried 2 test cases but its not covering the whole line. can you please elaborate on your alternative soln.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if your whole code is just `x = y != ... y : string.empty` you need two difefrent test-cases, one for the condition passing and one for it failing.

This can be achieved in two ways. One would be to create a test-method for every case:

```
string MethodToTest(string y) {
    return y != /* whatever your condition is */ ? y : string.empty
}
[Test]
public void Test1() {
    Assert.AreEqual(MethodToTest("PassingCondition"), "PassingCondition");
}
[Test]
public void Test2() {
    Assert.AreEqual(MethodToTest("NotPassingCondition"), string.empty);
}
```

Other way would be to create one method and add `TestCase`-attribute to it:

```
[TestCase("PassingCondition", Result = "PassingCondition")]
[TestCase("NotPassingCondition", Result = string.empty)]
public bool TheTest(string y) {
    return MethodToTest(y);
}
```

However both appraoches are equal in means of code-coverage. It depends on the actual condition how you achieve code-coverage. But you didn´t provide the actual condition making it impossible for us to answer that specific point.

EDIT: As you also provided Rhino-mocks (which I´m not familiar with) I assume what you pass as condition is returned by a method which you want to mock. So mock this method once returning a passing condition and one return a failing condition.

Comment: actually we are using Rhino Mock for testing and the attributes you used in the sample is of Nunit. Instead we have used the same process u have provided in the first method still we are unable to get full code coverage

Comment: I don´t know if rhino knows `[TestCase]`-attribute, however you may still use the first approach with `[TestMethod]` instead of `[Test]`.

Comment: FYI - Rhino Mocks is for mocking, not for the test attributes. NUnit, XUnit, MSTest etc all contain the test attributes like TestCase, Test etc...albeit different depending on which one you use.

Here is a comparison of the test frameworks: https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html

Comment: @ShaneYu I already assumed so, however I was not sure if it also supports test-attributes. But thanks for clearifying

Comment: @HimBromBeere So what testing framework are you using? MSTest, Xunit, NUnit or another?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't aiming for 100% code coverage if that is all you are doing. Unit tests that don't properly test anything are a waste of time and maintainability.

In order to full test (100%) a ternary operator, you need to test all conditions.

Consider a simple Boolean variable 'isMorning' which when true returns 'Morning' and false returns 'Afternoon'. You would need to write a test which has 'isMorning' set to 'true' and thus the expected result is 'Morning', then another test which has 'isMorning' set to 'false' and thus the expected result is 'Afternoon'.

```
public void Test1() {
  var isMorning = true;
  var result = isMorning ? "Morning" : "Afternoon";
  Assert.AreEqual("Morning", result);
}

public void Test2() {
  var isMorning = false;
  var result = isMorning ? "Morning" : "Afternoon";
  Assert.AreEqual("Afternoon", result);
}
```

Hope this helps.

FYI - If you use something like JetBrains DOTCOVER, it will highlight code not tested.